# Client side validation for manual entry in text field of date picker

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular js  bootstrap datepicker. I want to validate the string entered manually in the text field of datepicker and show the string in red if invalid date. How can I perform client side validation as ng-model doesn't hold a string. Thanks